# Posts from a site are displayed wrongly on another site on profile page on Android app

Tags: bug, profile-page, android-app

The "A troubling Moderator" question was asked on **Meta Stack Overflow**, but the app displays it in **English Language & Usage** box:

[image]

App version is 1.0.51, phone model is HTC One E8 (running Android 4.4.2) and I'm not Rico.

Comment: Able to replicate. App version 1.0.51, Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.3.